# Start Transaction causes an error when creating an event in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, transactions, mysql-event

For whatever reason, phpMyAdmin won't allow me to create an event with Start transaction. This is what I'm using:

```
CREATE EVENT `set_history`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-9-29 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DISABLE ON SLAVE
DO BEGIN

 START TRANSACTION;


INSERT INTO historical_transactions SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE domain IN (SELECT domain FROM domain JOIN accounts ON domain.accessAbility_ID = accounts.accessAbility_ID WHERE accounts.`renew_at` = DATE(NOW()));

DELETE FROM `transactions` WHERE domain IN (SELECT domain FROM domain JOIN accounts ON domain.accessAbility_ID = accounts.accessAbility_ID WHERE accounts.`renew_at` = DATE(NOW()));

UPDATE `accounts` SET `renew_at`= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE `renew_at` = DATE(NOW());

COMMIT;
END
```

The START TRANSACTION, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and COMMIT all work when run outside of the event. This is the error I keep getting:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8**

Hoping you can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define DELIMITER to something else (eg: `$$`) other than (`;`) and redefine it back to (`;`) at the end.

Basically, PHPMyAdmin parser will interpret `;` as an execution trigger, and it will try to trigger the query, instead of taking it in whole as a `Create` statement for the event. So redefining the delimiter helps in bypassing the execution.

Do the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `set_history`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-9-29 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DISABLE ON SLAVE
DO BEGIN

 START TRANSACTION;


INSERT INTO historical_transactions SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE domain IN (SELECT domain FROM domain JOIN accounts ON domain.accessAbility_ID = accounts.accessAbility_ID WHERE accounts.`renew_at` = DATE(NOW()));

DELETE FROM `transactions` WHERE domain IN (SELECT domain FROM domain JOIN accounts ON domain.accessAbility_ID = accounts.accessAbility_ID WHERE accounts.`renew_at` = DATE(NOW()));

UPDATE `accounts` SET `renew_at`= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) WHERE `renew_at` = DATE(NOW());

COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```